# How can I change data- attributes on an element through the Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, console

```
<aa class="Cul" data-name="James">James</aa>
```

I want to change `data-name` to something else, like "Jack".

For now, I know that I can change class name by using:

```
document.querySelector('aa[class="Cul"]').className = 'Jack';
```

So I applied this to change data-name

```
document.querySelector('aa[data-name="James"]').className = 'Jack';
// or
document.querySelector('aa[data-name="James"]').data-name = 'Jack';
```

But this is not working. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`data-*` attributes are accessible in JS through the `.dataset` object, you can do it like this:

```js
document.querySelector('aa[data-name="James"]').dataset.name = 'Jack';
```

Comment: @Hasker you're welcome. If this solved your problem you can accept my answer using the checkmark button on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Good question -- this one is a little tricky!

For most properties on an HTML element, you'll want to use the `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` functions, so for example:

```
document.querySelector('aa[data-name="James"]').setAttribute("data-name", "Jack")
// Should return Jack
document.querySelector('aa[data-name="James"]').getAttribute("data-name")
```

On a side note, when using JavaScript to access CSS or HTML properties whose names have dashes, you have to convert them to camel case because dashes are not allowed in property names -- they get interpreted as subtraction.